# NoReverseMatch at /revision/login_user/ Reverse for 'module-add' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: django

I am getting the following error in Django:

```
NoReverseMatch at /revision/login_user/ Reverse for 'module-add'
with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried:
```

[]I am not really sure why i am getting this error.

These are my views for logging in: (Traceback refers to here)

```
def login_user(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            modules = Module.objects.filter(user=request.user)
            return render(request, 'revision/index.html', {'modules': modules})
        else:
            return render(request, 'revision/login.html', {'error_message': 'Your account has been disabled'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'revision/login.html', {'error_message': 'Invalid login'})
return render(request, 'revision/login.html')
```

Same with register:

```
def register(request):
  form = UserForm(request.POST or None)
  if form.is_valid():
    user = form.save(commit=False)
    username = form.cleaned_data['username']
    password = form.cleaned_data['password']
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            modules = Module.objects.filter(user=request.user)
            return render(request, 'revision/index.html', {'modules': modules})

context = {
    "form": form,
}
return render(request, 'revision/register.html', context)
```

Both refer to the line of return render(request, 'revision/index.html', {'modules': modules}) 
How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This may be to do with your urls.py.

Have you included your revisions/urls.py in your [project_name]/urls.py?

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('revisions.urls')),
]
```

Also, have you a urlpattern in revesions/urls.py, which refers to a view method which does not exist?

Such as:

```
url(r'^module-add/$', views.module-add, name="module-add"),
```

Comment: Also check your templates, and make sure and url's you are using there are defined in the urls.py, and if you imported your revisions/urls.py into project_name/urls.py with a namespace, then you should use that namespace when refering to the url